# What is the best way to geocode large sets as a background process in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geocoding, background-process

I am implementing a contact importer and will be geocoding the contacts that are imported.  If a user imports 1000 contacts, geocoding is way too slow.  Essentially I would like to start a background process to geocode the contacts after they are imported and somehow report the status to a log.

Does this sound like the best way to do this?  If so, can I do this with some simple ruby/rails?  I have the javan-whenever gem which is essentially a ruby API for CRON but I would rather this be an immediately spawned background process after importing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of plugins that can help you do this:

1. [BackgroundDRb](http://backgroundrb.rubyforge.org/)
2. [Spawn](http://github.com/tra/spawn)

Answer (score 2):

There's also [Delayed Job](http://github.com/tobi/delayed_job).

Answer (score 0):

Tony, you might want to check out http://www.simpleworker.com too, takes care of all the processing management and monitoring as well as scheduling (like cron) if you need it.